# How to extract few bits or bytes from a byte array?

Tags: c, arrays, bit-manipulation, bit, endianness

I want a function which would help me to extract few bits or bytes from a starting bit position from a byte array. The order of the byte array is `LSB`. The skeleton of the code is as follows:

```
typedef unsigned char uint8;
typedef unsigned short uint16;
uint16 ExtractBitsOrBytes(uint16 StartBit, uint8 *ByteArray, uint16 BitsWanted)
{
    uint16 Result;
    ...
}
```

How can I implement this logic in `C`?. Any example or starting point is much appreciated.

Comment: Divide `StartBit` to 8 to calculate starting index in array. Then calculate how many bits to shift and `AND` mask to get only necessary bits.

Comment: C has types `uint16_t` and `uint8_t` defined in `<stdint.h>` - perhaps you should use these instead.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yeah you are right but these are project specifics.

Comment: This is the starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255692/grabbing-n-bits-from-a-byte; and probably `>> 3` or `/ 8`; and `& 7` or ` % 8`.

Comment: Yeah...your output may span a couple bytes, so you will, in general, have to get the low byte, and, shift down, get high byte, and, shift up, or into result.

Comment: @MartinJames Could you give me an example or so?

Comment: Just plan it out on paper.  Work out which bytes to get, how to get the needed bits out, how much to shift them to get them into the  correct offset so you can or them into your result.

Comment: What is the `StartBit` and what is the `BitsWanted`? I assume `StartBit` is the starting index and `BitsWanted` is the number of the bits you wanted to get.

Comment: @kurtfu `StartBit` is the index of the bit in the byte array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not fully specified: *LSB* refers to the order of bytes in memory for integral types spanning more than one byte. In your case you must specify how the bits are numbered in the array and composed to form the value extracted.

It would make sense to number the bits from 0, such that bit `n` is the bit with value `1 << (n % 8)` in the byte at offset `n / 8`.  For consistency, the bit with the lowest number should become the least significant bit of the extracted value. This convention is consistent with LSB as extracting 16 bits at offset 0 yields the value of the `uint16` stored in the first 2 bytes of the array.

Here is a naive implementation with this convention:

```c
typedef unsigned char uint8;
typedef unsigned short uint16;

uint16 ExtractBitsOrBytes(uint16 StartBit, const uint8 *ByteArray, uint16 BitsWanted) {
    // assuming BitsWanted <= 16
    uint16 result = 0;
    uint16 i;
    for (i = 0; i < BitsWanted; i++) {
        result |= (uint16)((ByteArray[StartBit >> 3] >> (StartBit & 7)) & 1) << i;
        StartBit++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note however that the convention used for monochrome bitmaps on many systems is different: the leftmost pixel corresponds to the most significant bit of the first byte, a convention inherited from choices made in the late 70s, mixing MSB and LSB, that made graphics software more complicated than it should have been.

Comment: My I know why there is this condition `BitsWanted <= 16` ? What to do in case of `BitsWanted = 32` ?

Comment: @Dennis.M: if you want to extract more than 16 bits at a time, make the return type if the function larger. `uint16` is likely to have just 16 bits. Also change the type of `result` and the cast `(uint16)`.