# Extract the first n bits of an unsigned int in C

Tags: c, bit-shift, bitmask

I want to write a function which extracts the first n bits starting by the MSB of a given uint16. I'm working with bitmasks for the first time and haven't found an elegant solution as far.
I've written a similar function for the last n bits starting by the LSB which uses a bitmask looking like

```
(1 << n) - 1
```

and think this works.

If I have the value `0b1010001100000101` my function creates the bitmask (for n = 3 it looks like `0b111`) and after that, uses the &-operator to check if the bits are present.

Which way should I use to get the first n bits?

I would be really happy if someone explain this to me because I want to understand how it works.

Thank you!

Comment: If by 'first' you mean the least significant bits they are `(uval << (16-n)) >> (16-n)`. If you mean the most significant bits they are `(uval >> (16-n)) << (16-n)`. In each case, the unwanted bits are shoved off the end, and zeros are shifted back in.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need a mask to extract the most significant bits of an `unsigned int`: just shift the value right by the width of the type less the number of bits:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint16_t extract_msbits(uint16_t x, int n) {
    if (n <= 0)
        return 0;
    else
    if (n < 16)
        return x >> (16 - n);
    else
        return x;
}
```

If the extracted bits should stay in place, you really mean to mask off the lower bits. Here is a solution:

```
#include <limits.h>

uint16_t mask_msbits(uint16_t x, int n) {
    if (n <= 0)
        return 0;
    else
    if (n < 16)
        return x & (~0U << (16 - n));
    else
        return x;
}
```

The expression `(1 << n) - 1` has undefined behavior if `n < 0` or `n` is greater or equal to 15 if the width of `int` is 16. For this reason, you should write `(1U << n) - 1` to compute a mask for an `unsigned int` or a `uint16_t`, but it still fails on 16-bit systems if `n` is 16 or larger, which might be a valid argument for the function. To avoid this issue, either use a test to compute a mask of `0xFFFF` for `n == 16` or use `(1UL << n) - 1`.

Comment: _"... but it still fails on 16-bit systems"_ How to solve that?

Comment: @Zakk: I amended the answer with 2 solutions, none of which is fully satisfying.

Comment: Your else-if formatting is rather curious. Is this formatting used by any projects?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: I use this style in [quickjs](https://github.com/bellard/quickjs) and qemacs. It is consistent with indenting the body of `else if` by the same amount as the initial `if` branch, whether `else` and `if` appear on the same line or not. Breaking the line between `else` and `if` allows for all the conditions to align vertically.

Answer (score 0):

#### A simple solution:

What you can do is to right shift your `uint16_t` integral value, by `16 - n` bits. Thus, only `n` bits remain.

Assume you have a type `uint16_t` and an integral object of this type with value `43558` named `x`:

```c
uint16_t x = 43558U;
```

Right shifting by `16 - n` bits:

```c
x >>= (16U - n);

// Or if you want to keep x intact

uint16_t y = x >> (16U - n);
```

Will store the first `n` bits in `x`. However, it will be padded with zeroes. Therefore, you need to perform bitwise `AND` (`&`) to test for the presence of `1` and `0` in this resulting `x`.

#### In case you are learning:

- Read [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255692/grabbing-n-bits-from-a-byte) answers on StackOveflow about **grabbing `n` bits**
- Read [this](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/bit-manipulation-with-bitwise-operators-and-bit-masks/) amazing article on **bit manipulation**

Comment: I understand. Your answer provides the correct solution, but ASAIK, OP is not going to push this code to production, so I am just providing many simple alternative and learning resources

Comment: The C++ references are not precise enough regarding the bit correspondance: MSdoc: *The N bits in a bitset are indexed by integer values from 0 to N - 1, where 0 indexes the first bit position and N - 1 the final bit position.* and *`operator[]` returns a reference to a bit at a specified position in a bitset if the bitset is modifiable; otherwise, it returns the value of the bit at that position.*

Comment: Also, **For unsigned `a` and for signed and non-negative `a`, the value of `a >> b` is the integer part of `a/2^b`**. This is from C++17 standard. For `a = 0`, this is **defined behavior**

Comment: @chqrlie You are correct, I just tested `bitset[0]` and it indeed is LSB. Sorry for this mistake! I removed my C++ reference. Thanks once again for pointing out.

Comment: I am amazed at how imprecise both cppreference and the MS doc is!

Comment: Regarding the undefined behavior, the problem is when `b` is greater or equal to the width of `int`.

Comment: @chqrlie I got confused because I recently wrote a IPv4 header parser, and used `bitset` for the purpose. It was a stream data, so **apparently** in my mind it was like the MSB bits are being indexed by `b[0]`, while it was just the nature of stream data that they arrived earlier. Sorry once again for debating over my mistake.

Comment: @chqrlie Indeed! It is a major assumption that you never try to extract first 17 bits from a 16 bit number, using this simple mechanism with no exception handling, or input validation.

Comment: Never mind extracting 17 bits... if you pass 0, which is legitimate, and type `int` has a width of 16 too, which is the case on 16-bit systems, `(x >> 16)` has undefined behavior. `>>` and `<<` are not defined if the shift number is greater or equal to the width of the promoted left operand.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to mask off all but the top `n` bits, you can simply shift right then left:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/**
 * @brief Masks all but top `n` bits
 * @param number Input number
 * @param n Number of bits to preserve. Must be >= 0 and <= 16
 * @return Original number with all but the top `n` bits masked off
 */
uint16_t msb_n(uint16_t number, const unsigned n) {
    assert(n <= 16 && "cannot shift more than 16 bits.");
    number >>= (16 - n);
    number <<= (16 - n);
    return number;
}
```